# Can we have two Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory location for one repo in one azure-pipeline yaml file to publish two different debian installer

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-artifacts

I want to create two debian installers (`packageName1` & `packageName2`) in same repo of azure-pipeline with same `feed`. Below is the task of my azure-pipeline.yaml file

```
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: 'Publish artifacts'
            inputs:
              pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              artifactName: 'Installer package and anti-virus scan results'
        
          - task: UniversalPackages@0
            displayName: Publish univeral package-1
            inputs:
              command: publish
              publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              vstsFeedPublish: '$(packageFeed)'
              vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(packageName1)'
              packagePublishDescription: ''
              versionOption: custom
              versionPublish: $(packageVersion1)
            condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/'))

          - task: UniversalPackages@0
            displayName: Publish univeral package-2
            inputs:
              command: publish
              publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              vstsFeedPublish: '$(packageFeed)'
              vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(packageName2)'
              packagePublishDescription: ''
              versionOption: custom
              versionPublish: $(packageVersion2)
            condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/'))
```

But when I am downloading artifact for one of the package installer through az command:

```
az artifacts universal download \
  --organization "https://myplatform.visualstudio.com/" \
  --feed "my-feed" \
  --name $packageName1 \
  --version $packageVersion1 \
  --path .
```

the packages and files of `packageName2` are also getting downloaded. I feel that's because I am using same `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` location to store/publish the artifacts for both packages. Can I use different location for both installer packages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subfolder under `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` for each project and publish each artifact separately.

There aren't 'multiple artifact directories', but you can create as many folders under the directory as you want and then pass the subfolder into the build and publish tasks.

Comment: So is this a valid task ?

          ```- task: UniversalPackages@
            displayName: Publish univeral package-1
            inputs:
              command: publish
              publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/subfolder'
              vstsFeedPublish: '$(packageFeed)'
              vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(packageName1)'
              packagePublishDescription: ''
              versionOption: custom
              versionPublish: $(packageVersion1)
            condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/'))```

Comment: Yes you can add as many subfolders to the publish directory as you need.

Comment: @jesshouwing: I am getting below error when added `publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/mybuild'` :

`2022-02-15T.8Z Script contents:
2022-02-15T.8Z cp os-package/my-installer_* /home/vsts/work/1/a/mybuild
2022-02-15.8Z ===Starting Command Output ===
2022-02-15.8Z #[debug]/usr/bin/bash arg: --noprofile
2022-02-15.8Z #[debug]/usr/bin/bash arg: --norc
2022-02-15.8Z #[debug]   /home/vsts/work/_temp/36e14e97.sh
2022-02-15.8Z [command]/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/36e14e97.sh
2022-02-15.8Z cp: target '/home/vsts/work/1/a/mybuild' is not a directory`

Comment: So add `mkdir mybuild` to ensure the folder exists.

Comment: you mean `mkdir $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/mybuild` right ?

Comment: Make sure whatever task you have before that is supposed to put stuff in that folder is doing so. The publish artifact task should have something to publish here.